# How should I design a graph database for an organization employess?

Tags: database, neo4j, nosql

I want to represent all of employees of an organization in a graph database, in particular Neo4j.

I decided to define a node for each employee where each node has a name, job title, email and etc. however, this way my graph becomes a set of unrelated nodes. how would be the best way for presenting all of information about employees ?

Comment: It really depends on what relationships your queries will be using. For example, if you would like to handle management hierarchies, then organize users in a tree-like structure based on a `MANAGING` (or `IS_MANAGER_OF`) relationship. If you have a background in relational databases, you might find [The Definitive Guide to Graph Databases for the RDBMS Developer](https://neo4j.com/resources/rdbms-developer-graph-white-paper/) useful.

Comment: I would like store and query data about individuals. for example, what is Johns hobby ? or what is his email address ? actually relationships are not important. but I have been asked to store data as graph database.

Comment: Using a graph DB when relationships are not important is a strange request... anyways, there are still parts that you could model with a graph. For example: assign a node to the individual hobbies. This will allow you to list hobbies by popularity: `MATCH (h:Hobby)<-[:HAS_HOBBY]-(p:Person) RETURN h.name, count(p) AS popularity ORDER BY popularity DESC`

Comment: There is no single "best" graph data model for organizations. The best data model for you depends on not only what data you have, but also what your use cases are.

Comment: @GaborSzarnyas I understand that it is a strange request :) Thank you for your suggestions.